# Sending information from LeadsBridge post to apex salesforce rest Service

Tags: facebook, web-services, rest, apex, salesforce-service-cloud

I'm trying to receive fields from an Integration of LeadsBridge platform linked with Facebook, so I made a RestService on apex in Salesforce to get the information, but It seems that LeadsBridge send the information in a different way that a Post json used to do.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/CarsyncLeadsBridge/*')
global class CarsyncLeadsBridge{



   @HttpPost
    global static Map<String,String> doPost(
            String id, String created_time, String campaign_id, String adset_id, 
            String ad_id, String email, String full_name, String phone_number, String mensaje){

        try {
            MSystem.debug(id+' - '+full_name+' - '+created_time+' - '+campaign_id+' - '+adset_id+' - '+adset_id+' - '+ad_id+' - '+email+' - '+phone_number);
```

But is not working, LeadsBridge can't consume it and it throw error before consume , so I try:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/CarsyncLeadsBridge/*')
global class CarsyncLeadsBridge{



   @HttpPost
    global static Map<String,String> doPost(){

        try {
 String id = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');
            String created_time = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('created_time');
            String campaign_id = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('campaign_id');
            String adset_id = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('adset_id');
            String ad_id = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('ad_id');
            String email = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('email');
            String full_name = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('full_name');
            String phone_number = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('phone_number');
            String mensaje = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('mensaje');

            System.debug(id+' - '+full_name+' - '+created_time+' - '+campaign_id+' - '+adset_id+' - '+adset_id+' - '+ad_id+' - '+email+' - '+phone_number);
```

This one is succesful on LeadsBridge but when I try to get the parameters they doesn't exist and produce a Nullpointer Exception.
Anybody know truly how do I should get the fields when I being receiving information from a post method from this platform (LeadsBridge).

Thanks for your help.

PD: I did try the both ways with ARC tester from Google Chrome and they worked fine.

Comment: I don't see where you ever capture the request

Comment: In the first one, you don`t need to, when you use @RestResource it means that automatically the apex service gonna capture it, in the second one I try to use  apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('field') to do it.. but it seems that it doesn't the the proper one..

Comment: Guess I've never built one where I used `RestRequest request = RestContext.request;` and `RestResponse response = RestContext.response;` and then serialize it